# Trying to understand this code adders[[1]](5)

Tags: r, lapply

The code below is from the *Advanced R* book by Hadley Wickham. It is a function in a function with `lapply`, not sure if it would qualify as a functional, but that's besides the point.  The code is made of two function `add()` defined as:

```
 add <- function(x) {
    function(y) x+y
 }
```

Then he uses `add()` along with `adders` "object" which behaves like a function, but I am not understanding the logic.  I say it behaves like a function because you can write code like this `adders[[1]](10)`, so it looks like `adders[[1]]` is a function.  Any way, he defined `adders` as:

```
adders <- lapply(1:10,add)
```

It looks to me like the 10 in `adders[[1]](10)` is "y" value in `add()` function. The pieces in 1:10 are fed into add through `lapply` represent the x of the `add()` function, but I am not sure I understand the logic.

Comment: See `environment(adders[[1]])$x`. He created a list of functions while storing a different `x` value within each functions environment (by specifying it within `lapply(1:10, ...)`). Then, when you do `adders[[1]](5)` You are feeding `5` to the `y` argument (because `adders[[1]]` is defined as `function(y) x+y`) which being added to the already stored `x` (which equals 1 in this case - as the function looks for the `x` in its parent environment first), so the end result is `6`.

Comment: When I run this piece of code, I see x = 10 for all list of 10 functions. Not sure what is going on.

Comment: `environment(adders[[1]])$x` or `environment(adders[[6]])$x` give you `10`?

Comment: The explanation in that [passage](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html#lazy-evaluation) seems pretty clear to me. What specifically are you having trouble understanding?

Comment: @nrussell, It wasn't clear to me how y gets "filled" or evaluated. I can see how apply puts the 1:10 one by one in add, which would stand for "x", but it wasn't clear to me when and how y gets called and filled.  Also if you write add(5) you get an error, so I couldn't understand the add() function, it's like it's an incomplete function, at the surface you wouldn't know what to feed it.

Comment: `add(5)` isn't an error, it's just returning a function - e.g. execute `add(5)(10)`. But you are speaking in the past tense, so it sounds like you understand the example now?

Comment: I am almost there, but still confused with "y", how is y accessed and filled? Because when you write adders[[1]](5).  The 5 is assigned to y, but it feels like it should go to "x" since when you coded add() the x was the only element that went inside ().

Comment: Also what makes adders[[x]] behave like a function, we didn't define it as a function, at least not in the classic way of function definition adders <- function(x){---}.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Also what makes adders[[x]] behave like a function, we didn't define
>   it as a function, at least not in the classic way of function
>   definition adders <- function(x){---}

Presumably by "classic way", you mean a named function, and are referring to the last line in `add`:

```
function(y) x + y
```

Functions, like the above, don't have to have an associated name - these are called anonymous functions. For example, you can try running

```
(function(a, b) a + b)(1, 2)
```

and it will be evaluated immediately, returning 3 - even though you didn't assign it (to) a name. And since it wasn't assigned to anything, it disappears after it finishes evaluating. Also note the following:

```
class((function(a, b) a + b))
#[1] "function"
```

---

Here's another example to drive this home:

```
add <- function(x) {
  force(x)
  function(y) x + y
  ## ^^^^^^^^^^^
  ## functionally equivalent to:
  ##
  ## f <- function(y) x + y
  ## return(f)
}

add_explicit <- function(x) {
  force(x)
  f <- function(y) x + y
  return(f)
}

(add(5))
#function(y) x + y
#<environment: 0x64106b0>

(add_explicit(5))
#function(y) x + y
#<environment: 0x637fe58>
```

While you *can* create a named function, as in `add_explicit`, since you aren't actually ever calling it by name (at least in the context of your question), there's no point in doing so.

---

> [...] but still confused with "y", how is y accessed and filled?
>   Because when you write adders[1]. The 5 is assigned to y, but it
>   feels like it should go to "x" since when you coded add() the x was
>   the only element that went inside ().

Let's apply David Arenburg's suggestion about inspecting the function's environment to `add(...)` and `add_explicit(...)`:

```
ls.str(envir = environment(add(42)))
#x :  num 42

ls.str(envir = environment(add_explicit(42)))
#f : function (y)  
#x :  num 42
```

Regarding `adders[[1]](5)` - which is equivalent to `add(1)(5)`, since the expression used to create it was `lapply(1:[whatever], add)` - you said you feel like 5 should correspond to the `x` argument, rather than the (nested) `y` argument. But as the examination directly above shows, `x` is effectively no longer a function parameter - its value is "fixed" with whatever it was when `add(x)` was called - 42 in my case. Since `add` returned an anonymous function, `x` is all the corresponding environment shows. On the other hand, `add_explicit` assigned the expression to a name (within its associated environment), and you can see that `f` is a function of *only* `y`. Therefore, when you are calling `add([whatever])(5)`, *that* is why `5` corresponds to the `y` variable in the body of `add`.

---

Also, don't get too hung up on the `adders` object. It's just a `list` that happens to be storing functions, i.e.:

```
lapply(1:2, add)
#[[1]]
#function (y) 
#x + y
#<environment: 0x7425ce0>

#[[2]]
#function (y) 
#x + y
#<environment: 0x74259d0>
```

And although it might *appear* that `x` is still a (varying) parameter when inspected like this, its value has already been fixed (to `1` in the first case, and `2` and the second case). What's really important is this part - `function (y)` - indicating that the `list` created by `lapply` contains functions which accept a single argument (`y`). `x` is effectively "off the table" as far as the list is concerned.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I especially liked the last paragraph "And although it might Appear..." it drove the point home by potting everything together.  Thanks again, and happy new year!